# Google Chrome HTML Form Select

Tags: html, css, forms, google-chrome, html-select

I have a html form with a select box.

In firefox the select box, is relatively plain ie. white background, simple border etc.

However when viewing it in Google Chrome it applies its own styling making them look horrible, adding round edges, a grey and white gradient etc.

Does anyone know how I can remove this styling from my select boxes when viewing webkit browsers, so it looks the same as it does in firefox?

Thanks

Comment: what version of Chrome are you using? Not all version will render the same. Version 16 on Ubuntu renders input's without rounded corners.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest solution would be to use a CSS reset. This should normalize the styling as much as possible regardless of browser or OS.

Here's two of the more popular ones to try:

- http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
- http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/